# SQL Query in finding out the max number from a table with Null value

Tags: sql, sql-server

How Can I work out this requirement. Please help.

Client Table -  **CT**

```
ClientID      Balance  
123             10
123             20  
123             30
123             40  
124             50
124             60  
124             Null
```

I want to find our the max(Balance) from the CT Table.
Condition - > If there is no null value then I have to find out max(Balance) otherwise It should be Null. See below result, that am expecting.

```
ClientID     Balance  
123           40  
124           Null
```

Am writing the query as below. But Is there any more dynamic way to do?

```
Select ClientID,  
       CASE WHEN MIN(Balance) = NULL THEN  
                 NULL  
             ELSE  
                 MAX(Balance) END AS 'MaxBalance'  
From CT  
Group by clientID
```

Please let me know, is there any otheralternative?

Comment: What database are you using?  Is this SQL Server?

Comment: The alternative you are using now shouldn't even work as intended. What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: And what version?, @GordonLinoff - no, the query is not fine

Comment: "Dynamic" in SQL is a bad thing, unless necessary. The answer you provided is, to a decent first approximation, the best way to do this. It is simple, clear, and does what you need. Is there a reason you want a 'better' way to do this? Is there some problem to fix?

Comment: Just an aside; nothing equals NULL.  Try running SELECT CASE WHEN NULL=NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END and see what you get.  Also, MIN ignores any NULL values, so that's why your query won't work as intended (as @Lamak pointed out).

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Select ClientID,
       (CASE WHEN count(balance) < count(*)
             THEN NULL 
             ELSE MAX(Balance)
        END) AS MaxBalance
From CT
Group by clientID
```

Or, a bit more cumbsersome, but perhaps clearer:

```
Select ClientID,
       (CASE WHEN sum(case when balance is null then 1 else 0 end) > 0
             THEN NULL 
             ELSE MAX(Balance)
        END) AS MaxBalance
From CT
Group by clientID
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
SELECT clientid
    , balance
FROM 
    ( 

        SELECT clientid
            , balance
            , row_number()
                over(   partition by clientid
                    order by CASE WHEN balance IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
                        , balance DESC
                ) r
        FROM ct
    ) n 
WHERE r = 1
```

Comment: This is worse - the subquery will add nothing, and you sort the entire list to find 1 value.

Comment: @David Manheim:  The subquery is necessary to the requirement.  We only want one row per client, and you can't use analyticals in the where clause.  The query will return one row per client, not just one row.  As to worse: I haven't checked this case vs. the various GROUP BY solutions, but analytical functions often outperform them.

Comment: That is true, but the statement above looks like a good solution that will execute well. The analytic subquery you use is more expensive than the `case`/`group by` above, since it must order the entire set, by first a computed column then by a stored value - no optimization could be done before computing this for every value. Additionally, unless a custom index were created on the computed value, the indexes would not cover this. In the statement used in the question above, if it is indexed by `clientid`, (and then possibly by `balance`) there is a benefit, in addition to using a single pass.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what datatype [Balance] is, but if it is an int, you can do the following:

```
Select ClientID, NULLIF(MAX(ISNULL(Balance,2147483647)),2147483647)
From CT 
GROUP BY ClientID
```

If [Balance] is not an int, just replace `2147483647` with the max value of that datatype.

The danger, of course, would be if you *really do* have a client with a balance of 2147483647.  In such a case their max balance would show as null.

Answer (score 0):

This will work on SQL 2005+

```
; WITH a AS (       
SELECT DISTINCT ClientID
FROM CT 
WHERE Balance IS NULL   )     

SELECT t.ClientID, MAX(t.Balance) "MaxBalance"
FROM CT t
    LEFT JOIN a ON t.CLientID = a.ClientID
WHERE a.ClientID IS NULL
GROUP BY t.CLientID
UNION ALL
SELECT a.ClientID, NULL
FROM a
```

Answer (score 0):

This works but is not very elegant:

```
SELECT SUB.ClientID, CASE (SELECT COUNT(ClientID) 
                           FROM MyTable MT 
                           WHERE Balance IS NULL 
                           AND MT.ClientID = SUB.ClientID)
                    WHEN 0 THEN (SELECT MAX(Balance) 
                                 FROM MyTable MT 
                                 WHERE MT.ClientID = SUB.ClientID)
                    ELSE NULL END AS Balance
FROM (SELECT ClientID 
      FROM [MyTable] 
      GROUP BY ClientID) SUB
```

Comment: All, Looks, my query works fine, easy and simple, Comparing to all. I was expected any SQL keywords we can use to implement.